# Acción al finalizar un vídeo en página web

Tags: php

Tengo un problema para conseguir que después de reproducir un vídeo en una web esta me readireccione automáticamente a otra página.

Con este código me funciona para navegadores de PC pero en el móvil aparece el vídeo para darle al Play manualmente (en PC reproduce automáticamente como yo quiero) pero no pasa a la otra página al finalizar la reproducción.

```
    <video id="theVideo" autoplay scr=<?php echo $Video;?>
    </video>

    <script type='text/javascript'>
        document.getElementById('theVideo').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
        var form = document.createElement( "form" );
        form.setAttribute( "name", "formulario" );
        form.setAttribute( "action", "http://www.ejemplo.com/siguientepagina.php" );
        form.setAttribute( "method", "post" );
        var input = document.createElement( "input" );
        input.setAttribute( "name", "Indice" );
        input.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
        input.setAttribute( "value", <?php echo $Indice;?> );
        form.appendChild( input );
        document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[0].appendChild( form );
        document.formulario.submit();
        ;})
    </script>
```

Comment: Tienes un error en la etiqueta video has puesto scr en lugar de `src` . Por otro lado veo que has creado un formulario y lo envías. No seria mas fácil meter una redirección al acabar el video?.

Comment: No te arranca porque los videos no se arrancan solos en los navegadores. El autoplay solo te funciona si le pones, además muted.

Comment: tienes razón pero ahora me ocurre otro problema y es que el vídeo no arranca desde la variable $Video dentro del scr=<?php echo $Video;?> que contiene el link local donde está almacenado el vídeo (http://www.ejemplo.com/video.mp4). Lo del formulario es porque a la página del vídeo llegan datos anteriores por $post que hay que mover a la siguiente página a la que debería salta automáticamente una vez termine el vídeo.

Comment: Te puse una respuesta con lo que consultas. No obstante, indica en tu pregunta que contiene la variable `$Video` con un `var_dump()`

Comment: la variable $Video contiene la dirección local de almacenamiento del video "http ://www .ejemplo.com/video.mp4". Si pongo el código <video id="theVideo" autoplay src="<?php echo $Video;?>"></video> el vídeo no se ejecuta pero si pongo <video id="theVideo" autoplay <?php echo $Video;?>></video> si que se ejecuta automáticamente en cualquier navegador de PC y salta a otra página automáticamente al terminar. En navegadores de smartphone no se ejecuta automáticamente siendo ese el problema.

Comment: Pon el atributo `muted` es lo que le falta para que se reproduzca automáticamente, como te indico en mi respuesta. Lo raro es que con `src` puesto no se ejecute automáticamente.

Comment: he probado y tampoco funciona con muted, lo único que cambia es que no se escucha el sonido. Otra cosa, en el caso de los smartphones si le doy al play del vídeo se reproduce bien pero al terminar no pasa automáticamente a la otra página.

Comment: Actualizo mi respuesta de abajo, dado que en el caso de dispositivos móviles debes seguir unas indicaciones para sistemas android. En el caso de IOS, según dicen, está todo ok.

Comment: Que va, tampoco funciona. Ni siquiera el propio vídeo de ejemplo de Google se ejecuta automáticamente en smartphones Android: https://simpl.info/video/scripted/. Voy a desistir de forzar el autoplay, por lo que mi idea ahora es habilitar un botón manual de pasar a la siguiente página pero solo cuanto el vídeo haya terminado de reproducirse, pero vuelvo a otro problema y es que en smartphones no parece funcionar el "addEventListener" del código de JavaScript.

Comment: Has leído el enlace que te puse en la respuesta sobre los dispositivos Android?.

Answer (score 0):

Abajo te pongo el código corregido. Los vídeos ya no se autoejecutan en los navegadores, debido a las nuevas políticas que han integrado. Si quieres que se autoejecute deberás poner el atributo `muted`, como te lo indico en la etiqueta `video`.

Por otro lado, como te indiqué, tienes un error tipográfico en la etiqueta `video`, pusiste `scr` en lugar de `src`.

Mi recomendación es que la llamada que haces lo hagas con Ajax. Es más cómodo, mas sencillo de leer, no obstante, no te lo pongo porque no se que tiene `siguientepagina.php` ni la variable `$Video` y no quiero inducirte a error.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    document.getElementById('theVideo').addEventListener('ended', function(e) {
    var form = document.createElement( "form" );
    form.setAttribute( "name", "formulario" );
    form.setAttribute( "action", "http://www.ejemplo.com/siguientepagina.php" );
    form.setAttribute( "method", "post" );
    var input = document.createElement( "input" );
    input.setAttribute( "name", "Indice" );
    input.setAttribute( "type", "hidden" );
    input.setAttribute( "value", <?php echo $Indice;?> );
    form.appendChild( input );
    document.getElementsByTagName( "body" )[0].appendChild( form );
    document.formulario.submit();
    ;})
</script>
```

En el caso de los móviles la cosa cambia según el sistema operativo. Si es android deberás seguir estas directrices:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2016/07/autoplay

Ya que no permiten que se ejecute solo en móviles sin la interacción humana en caso de no usar `muted`. Si lo usas deberás poner el atributo `play()` para que se autoejecute, pero se pausará si detecta una pista de audio.

En el caso de IOS no deberías tener problemas, con el atributo `muted`debería funcionar perfectamente.